# Rule when convert enum to its value in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript recently, and there are some rules I can't understand while using `enum`.
For example, I have an enum like this:

```js
enum FOO { 
    A = 'a'
}
```

When I write my code like this:

```
const test1: FOO = 'a';
const test2: FOO = FOO.A
```

When declaring `test1`, there would be an error:

> Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'FOO'.ts(2322)

I thougt `enum` can't convert to its value until seeing this code:

```
let fooKey: FOO = FOO.A;
switch (fooKey) { 
    case 'a': { }
}
```

In this case, typescript exactly convert my `string` into `enum`.
So could someone please tell me the rule when convert `enum` to its value in TypeScript?

Comment: In last case there is no conversion of `string` to `enum`. You are comparing a string against one string inside the enum collection.

Comment: Don't know what kind of answer you're expecting here. Yes, TypeScript allows you to _compare_ strings to enum-typed variables. No, TypeScript does not allow you to directly _assign_ strings to enum-typed variables.